# Android - Eclipse - What does docUri mean?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-cloud-print

I am working through this tutorial https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android for google cloud print. I am trying to add a print functionality to my application. However I have NO IDEA what docUri stands for/means/definition. I am trying to print the file "/sdcard/StudentLatePass.txt"

This is what I have so far,

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            //Print using Google Cloud Print
            Intent printIntent = new Intent(StudentActivity.this, PrintDialogActivity.class);
                printIntent.setDataAndType(docUri, "text/plain");
                printIntent.putExtra("title", "Student Late Pass");
                startActivity(printIntent);

            }// onClick
    });// btnPrintSDFile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docUri - URI of the document to be printed.

What is a URI? A uniform resource identifier (URI) is a string of characters used to identify a name or a resource ([Wiki URI](http://docUri%20-%20URI%20of%20the%20document%20to%20be%20printed%20%20What%20is%20a%20URI?%20A%20uniform%20resource%20identifier%20%28URI%29%20is%20a%20string%20of%20characters%20used%20to%20identify%20a%20name%20or%20a%20resource%20%28http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier%29.)).

I think that you can set it using:

```
printIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/StudentLatePass.txt")), "text/plain");
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Your answer just made sure that I graduate college on time!

Comment: No problem. Hope you enjoy the graduation ;)

Comment: @Hayden this thing not working with my code.. what could be the possible reason? It says invalid content i have tried with pdf also

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the documentation?  It's the URI of the doc you want to print.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setDataAndType(android.net.Uri, java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setDataAndType%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%29)

It even says so in the example:

> In the code above, replace the three parameters as follows:
>
> docUri - URI of the document to be printed
>
> docMimeType - MIME type of the document to be printed. We recommend that you use PDF (application/pdf) format
>
> docTitle - title of the printed document, arbitrary string that will be shown on the GCP management console as the print job's title

Answer (score 0):

docUri here is the Uri of the document you want to print.

```
String location ="/sdcard/StudentLatePass.txt";
File f = new File(location);
        Uri docUri =Uri.fromFile(f);
```